# Too many re-renders when accessing data from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am making a get request to an API that is linked to my database.

dataApi is a really big object with a lot of objects and arrays nested within it.

Some of the entries from the database are not having the full details that I need so I am filtering them to only show those with a length of > 5.

Now the issue is when I try to get the name of each entry which is split into either `Tag1, Tag2 or Tag3`.

Before this when I was accessing all the entries and getting the items within them there was no issue.

But when I try to filter them by the name and store the objects corresponding to that name in its state this issue arrises.

**Edit:**
When I `console.log(arr1)` it shows all the data but the moment I set the state to it it causes the error.

```
// Data from all entries in database
const [dataApi, setDataApi] = useState();
// Data for each of the tags
const [tag1, setTag1] = useState();
const [tag2, setTag2] = useState();
const [tag3, setTag3] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(URL).then((res) => {
    const data = res.data;
    setDataApi(data);
  });
}, []);

const getTagDetails = data => {
    const arr1 = [];
    const arr2 = [];
    const arr3 = [];
    data &&
        data.forEach(d => {
            // Entries into the database which do not have any tag information
            // have a size of 5 and those with all the details have a size of 6
            const sizeOfObject = Object.keys(d).length;
            // Only need database items with all the details
            if (sizeOfObject > 5) {
                const name = d["tags"]["L"][0]["M"]["name"]["S"];
                // Split the data for the tags into their respective name
                // Will be used to set individual datasets for each tag
                if (name === "Tag1") {
                    arr1.push(d);
                }
                if (name === "Tag2") {
                    arr2.push(d);
                }
                if (name === "Tag3") {
                    arr3.push(d);
                }
            }
        });
    setTag1(arr1);
    setTag2(arr2);
    setTag3(arr3);
};
getTagDetails(dataApi);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is you call **getTagDetails(dataApi)** inside of file so it causes this infinite rendering problem

Instead remove getTagDetails and try to call this functions after API resolved.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(URL).then((res) => {
    const data = res.data;
    getTagDetails(data)
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Happy to help :) This is common problem, so now you know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you have structured your `getTagDetails` function.  Each time you render, you call `getTagDetails()` and the first thing you do is **create a new array** for each tag.  When you call `setTag` with the new array, it will rerender.  You'll probably want to move the `getTagDetails` logic into the effect so it only runs once on mount (or add a dependency to the dependency array if you need to update on new data)